# Toggle Function with Button Onclick

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I had create a table with two method of toggle function, first toggle is toggle table row with its specific ID and second toggle is toggle all the table row. However, if i click on first toggle at first parent row, and then when i click on second toggle, the child of first parent will hide, **where it suppose follow other parent show their child and then click again to hide the child.** And if all child is shown, the image also should change from details_open.png become details_close.png

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <body>

    <body>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        function toggle(thisname, image) {
          var path = image.src;
          var filename = path.match(/.*\/([^/]+)\.([^?]+)/i)[1];
          if (filename == 'details_open') {
            image.src = 'details_close.png';
          }
          if (filename == 'details_close') {
            image.src = 'details_open.png';
          }
          tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')
          for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            if (tr[i].getAttribute(thisname)) {
              if (tr[i].style.display == 'none') {
                tr[i].style.display = '';
              } else {
                tr[i].style.display = 'none';
              }
            }
          }
        }



        $(function() {
          $('#btn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.td1').toggle();
          });
        });
      </script>

      <input type="button" id="btn" style="color:red" name=btn value="Toggle Child Accessories">
      <table class="w3-table-all">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td onclick="toggle(1,open_1);">
              <center><img id="open_1" src="details_open.png" style="width:20px;cursor: pointer;"></center>
            </td>
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <thead>
          <tr 1=fred style='display:none;' class='td1' id='td1'>
            <td> </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td onclick="toggle(2,open_2);">
              <center><img id="open_2" src="details_open.png" style="width:20px;cursor: pointer;"></center>
            </td>
            <td> E </td>
            <td> F</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <thead>
          <tr 2=fred style='display:none;' class='td1' id='td1'>
            <td> </td>
            <td> G </td>
            <td> H </td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correcly your need, you just need to control your rows's visibility to force toggle to hide or show all with his parameter display http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display

```
$('#btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var display = true;

    if ($('.td1:visible').length == $('.td1').length) {
        display = false;
    }

    $('.td1').toggle(display);
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJymRr?editors=1010

I hope this will help you

Comment: May i know how can swap the image from details_open.png become details_close.png according to the child toggle?

Comment: i try add some class in table and make changes in javascript part but it seen failed to swap the image https://codepen.io/wkt931029/pen/WKamXg

Comment: Something was wrong in the selector https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaVqLX?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can use jquery `toggleClass()`to swap the images using your css classes. [jquery toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). also noticed you have double `<body>` tag